# Implementation of Convolutional Neural Network in R language

Tags: r, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Is there any R package for Convolutional Neural Networks? I searched extensively but could not spot one. If anyone knows, then please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MXNetR` package for that. The command is `mx.symbol.Convolution()`

For the package documentation see:
http://mxnet-bing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-package/index.html

For a complete example in context see this tutorial:
http://mxnet-bing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-package/mnistCompetition.html